# Wordpress Convert queries to slashes using function.php

Tags: plugins, php, functions

Please check and explain why this wordpress rewrite rule isn't still working.

```
function myplugin_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^music/record-year/([^/]*)/?', 'music/?record_year=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I wanted if music/?record_year=2019 is visited, it should be music/record-year/2019 instead

Comment: If you visit `music/record-year/2019` does it work as expected? `music/?record_year=2019` redirecting to `music/record-year/2019` is a _redirect_ and has nothing to do (directly) with rewrite rules. Same goes for changing any links. Rewrite URLs make the URL work, but redirecting and links need to be handled separately.

Comment: The URL isn't working as expected,
Its showing 404 error